# Is there anything I can do to improve this question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682794/how-do-i-link-the-activestate-distribution-of-tcl-tk-to-homebrew-installed-pytho), quite specific, question on SO a while ago, and it has had no response. I even got the tumbleweed badge for it.

I don't actually need it to be answered now, as I have given up trying to solve it, and instead used Pycharm as a proper IDE.

I still feel that it is a valid and good question, so is the reason it has had no response just that no-one has had to solve it before?

I received the question ban as a result of lots of neutral questions like this one, and a couple of mildly bad questions which can't really be improved. So, I am looking at improving some of my older question like this one.

Is there anything in particular that is wrong with it, or is it just that none of the experts on SO use IDLE anyway?

Comment: I don't think you'd get a question ban on 0-vote questions *only*... Did you delete downvotes questions? These still count.

Comment: You didn't get question-banned because you have 0-vote questions. While the exact algorithm is secret, part of it has to do with negative-scoring questions, including deleted questions. You have a lot of deleted questions, and most of those had negative scores.

Comment: Good call on the Meta effect!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's not much you can do to improve the question, besides [removing the "Thanks" at the end](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/258777).  However, to get more attention to it, can:

- Edit the question to bump it to the front page.  Make good edits though; add more information, remove the "Thanks," etc.
- Answer questions/suggest edits until you have 75 reputation, then start a bounty.

I'd wait a few days before doing these, since this Meta question will give the question some attention (but maybe not from the right people).

Comment: Yeah, the thanks, hey and howdy niceties get real old real fast.  People reviewing a lot of questions are most impressed with how quickly the questioner can get to the point, and present the crux of the problem and nothing else.

Comment: If a question has any chattiness at all, it better be dry and contain a fleeting degree of technical intrigue or it is very off-putting. Even someone who doesn't mind a bit of prose in many case finds themselves impatient with long questions.